# Three-Tier architecture and LINQ to Entities

Tags: architecture, linq-to-entities, 3-tier

For a couple of years, I've been using the three-tier architecture (Presentation, Logic and Data Layer) to write applications. Usually, I am using tools such as .netTiers to generate the data layer and partially the logic layer. Everything is well defined and I love it.

I am now constraint to use LINQ to Entites (it appears that LINQ to SQL was abandoned by Microsoft) and I am really confused. It looks to me like the code generated by LINQ to Entites is a big mix of the logic and data layer on which I have very little control. In addition, I don't really like the fact that I have to use the classes (entities...) generated.

In the end, could you share your experiences and best practices with LINQ to Entities? Any idea how I could still have a well defined Three-Tier architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: I would really love to read where you found this information ?
"(it appears that LINQ to SQL was abandoned by Microsoft) "

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/DLINQ-Future

We would not like to invest in a dying technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian Cooper wrote good series about architecting application using Linq2Sql:

- [Part 1 Introduction](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2007/11/29/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2 Layered Architectures](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2007/11/30/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-2.aspx)
- [Part 3 DAOs and Repositories](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2007/12/02/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-3.aspx)
- [Part 4 Dynamic Queries](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2007/12/04/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-4.aspx)
- [Part 5](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/02/17/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-5.aspx)
- [Part 6 Mapping with XML files instead of Attributes](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/03/09/previous-architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-5.aspx)
- [Part 7](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/03/09/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-7.aspx)
- [Part 8](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/04/06/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-8.aspx)
- [Part 9](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/06/28/architecting-linq-to-sql-part-9.aspx)
- [Part 10](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/07/01/architecting-linq-to-sql-part-10.aspx)

Hope you find what you need.

Answer (score 2):

L2S is not dead, but it is basically complete.  Its an implementation ( Sql Adapter ) for Linq.  Linq is a language feature and will continue to expand as .net versions are released.

What makes Linq beautiful is the simplicity.  I for one, beyond additional providers ( like MySql, Firebird, etc... ) I don't really want them to muck it up.